# Printing intermediate steps in java freezes

Tags: java, debugging, swing, freeze, concurrency

I'm writing a java application that encrypts and decrypts the input by DES algorithm. First I made it without GUI and printed the intermediate steps in the output window by using `System.out.print();`. When the input is large, the calculations can take a while but when using the output window the intermediate steps where printed one by one while it was calculating. That was perfect.

Now I made a GUI for my program, using a JTextArea, called txtDebug for printing the intermediate steps:

```
public static void debug(String tekst){
txtDebug.setText(txtDebug.getText()+tekst+"\n");}
```

The problem: the intermediate steps aren't printed one by one anymore. If the input is large, the program just freezes and does nothing, until the calculations are all done, and then it prints the intermediate steps all at once.

Another problem: when I wasn't using the GUI, the program never crashed, now if the input is large enough, the program crashes: it freezes and just never comes back to life.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

You must do the work in a background worker thread. Doing it in the main thread will prevent Swing from processing events -> the UI will block.

- http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=swing.async
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've read about the SwingWorker but I'm not sure how to implement it, this is the structure of my program: I have a Functions.java which contains all the functions used for encryption and decryptions, 2 classes Encryption.java and Decryption.java, they call the right functions from Functions.java, and I have a Main.java class, which contains GUI and actionhandlers and call Encrypt.java or Decrypt.java. I've also added a function in Main.java so Encrypt.java & Decrypt.java can write debug info to the txtDebug. Which of these classes need to extend the SwingWorker?

Comment: None; SwingWorker is a utility class. See the example in the JavaDocs (second link in my answer). See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html

Comment: Thanks, I use the SwingWorker now in my Encrypt class to calculate in the background, and when the calculation is finished, I print the intermediate steps in my GUI. Now here's another problem: without GUI my program calculates very fast, about 100 iterations every second. With GUI and SwingWorker, my program calculates only by 1 iteration every second. How did this happen?

Comment: The UI takes a lot of cycles. Update only 3-4 times per second (use System.currentTimeMillis() to determine when you updated the UI the last time).

Answer (score 2):

The user interface is freezing because you're performing long running calculations on the Event Dispatch Thread, the thread responsible for processing events and repainting the UI.  To avoid this problem consider performing the encryption / decryption on a background thread, perhaps using a [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Regarding the second point about the user interface never coming back to life this could indicate another resource problem (e.g. memory).  You might want to run a profiler or JConsole to see the state of each thread when this problem occurs.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've read about the SwingWorker but I'm not sure how to implement it, this is the structure of my program: I have a Functions.java which contains all the functions used for encryption and decryptions, 2 classes Encryption.java and Decryption.java, they call the right functions from Functions.java, and I have a Main.java class, which contains GUI and actionhandlers and call Encrypt.java or Decrypt.java. I've also added a function in Main.java so Encrypt.java & Decrypt.java can write debug info to the txtDebug. Which of these classes need to extend the SwingWorker?